# Jquery & PHP : obtaining no result on jquery using ob_get_clean

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some template files in the project for example '/view/dynamic.html' containing these simple data :

```
 <div class="dynamic"></div>
```

On the client side : I have a clickable element on my web page using Jquery that posts an asynchronous request to the server side.

```
$('a.clickable').on('click', function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    var $type = $this.data('type');
    var $project_id = 1;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "php/zeek.php",
        data: { 
            'method': 'clicked',
            'type': $type,
            'project_id': $project_id 
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function($input)
        {
            console.log('result:' + $input);
        },
        error: function($request, $status, $error)
        {
            $('div.dynamic').replaceWith(
                '<div class="dynamic"><h2>'
                + $error + '</h2></div>');
            console.log($status + ' : ' + $error);
        }
    });
});
```

On the server side : 
I have a function that is displaying the content of the dynamic view file.

```
public function dynamic_display() {
    ob_start();
    include 'view/dynamic.html';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

and finally I have function that receives the request :

```
    case 'clicked':
        $type = strtolower($params['type']);

        if ($type == 'disconnect') {
            echo("? " . $this->dynamic_display() . " ?");
            return true;
        }
```

The problem :

when I test my function 'dynamic_display' with unit test, this function sends back the correct expected string. Using var_dump, I obtain :

```
string(28) "<div class="dynamic"></div>
"
```

When I click on the element on my page : I doesn't obtain the same result on the console

```
 "result:?  ?"
```

Why it doesn't work? What is happening? How should make it working?

Thanks & Regards!
Leo

Comment: Thanks for the answer : I have comment all other cases but I show you more things

Comment: On the top of my server side file : I handle the reception 

    <?php
    
    $zeek = new ZeekProject();
    
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $zeek->input($_POST);
    }

Comment: I created a function in the ZeekProject Class : public function input($params)
    {
        switch ($params['method']) {
        case 'clicked':
            $type = strtolower($params['type']);
            if ($type == 'disconnect') {
                echo("? " . $this->dynamic_display() . " ?");
                return true;
            }

            $this->error("unexpected type '$type'!");
            return false;
        }

        $this->error("unknown method '$method' with parameters "
        . var_dump($params));
        return false;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work when I use

```
include '/home/leo/zeek/view/dynamic.html';
```

instead of

```
include 'view/dynamic.html';
```

I am really surprised? Somebody could explained?